# trying to stem a string in natural language using python-2.7

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, stemming

I am importing from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

and I have a string as follows:

text_string="Hi Everyone  If you can read this message youre properly using parseOutText  Please proceed to the next part of the project"

I run this code on it:
words = " ".join(stemmer.stem(word) for word in text_string.split(" "))

and I get the following which has a couple of 'e' missing. Can't figure out what is causing it. Any suggestions? Thanks for the feedbacks

"hi everyon  if you can read this messag your proper use parseouttext  pleas proceed to the next part of the project"

Comment: You're using it correctly; it's the stemmer that's acting weird. What _must_ be causing it is too little training data, or the wrong balance, or simply the wrong conclusion. We can't expect perfection, but it's annoying when it happens with common words. It's also stemming "everything" to "everyth", as if it's a verb. At least here it's clear what it's doing. But "-e" is not a suffix in English...

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that is the answer to my question

Comment: Expanded it a bit into an answer. NB, I don't have any experience with the insides of the stemmer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using it correctly; it's the stemmer that's acting weird. It could be caused by too little training data, or the wrong balance, or simply the wrong conclusion by the stemmer's statistical algorithm. We can't expect perfection, but it's annoying when it happens with common words. It's also stemming "everything" to "everyth", as if it's a verb. At least here it's clear what it's doing. But "-e" is not a suffix in English...

The stemmer allows the option `ignore_stopwords=True`, which will suppress stemming of words in the stopword list (these are common words, usually irregular, that Porter thought fit to exclude from the training set because he got worse results when they are included.) Unfortunately it doesn't help with the particular examples you ask about.